# List the request- and session-scoped beans that are created by SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If there's a list of these already available on the web, please link it. I couldn't find any such thing using the Googles.

Request-scoped beans:

- `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

Session-scoped beans:

- `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it really depends on what you've told Spring to create, but you'd see this in a default setup.

REQUEST:

```
    for(String key : Collections.list(request.getAttributeNames())) {
        System.out.println( key );
    }
```

RESULT:

```
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.WEB_ASYNC_MANAGER
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.CONTEXT
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.OUTPUT_FLASH_MAP
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.FLASH_MAP_MANAGER
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_SOURCE
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.pathWithinHandlerMapping
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.uriTemplateVariables
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.THEME_RESOLVER
```

SESSION:

```
    for(String key : Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames())) {
        System.out.println( key );
    }
```

RESULT:

```
(empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring happens once, after the object creation, and this is a main thing to keep in mind when reasoning about autowiring and different scopes.

About your question, there's in fact no issue when it comes to injecting longer living beans inside a short-lived beans. Its only important that you're aware of it and that it fits your semantic.

Other way around is a bit trickier. So injecting shorter lived beans, inside a longer lived beans. The proper way for doing this is leaning on proxies. If you're injecting a request-scoped bean inside a session-scoped bean, and if the request-scoped bean is proxied, than the proxy will be created only once, but will create a request bean on each request.

Its a simplification of what is described in the docs and available at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: Considering the information in your answer, it might be more appropriate to change the list to request- and session-scoped beans that are "given" by Spring MVC?

Comment: This answer was posted before a major edit. Please don't downvote it for content.

Comment: well, the answer to your question before the edit is that you can inject beans to other beans regardless of the scope. The notion of Spring MVC "given" beans is not something that people will understand. HttpServletRequest and HttpSession are not spring beans so you can't autowire them

Comment: They can be autowired into a request-scoped bean. I'm not sure exactly how the Spring magic wraps them to allow for this, but it can definitely be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can autowire anything that Spring can build.  Whether or not you should is another matter.

For example, it is utterly senseless to autowire a bean with Step scope (from batch processing) to a request scoped bean.

Comment: This answer was posted before a major edit. Please don't downvote it for content.